# AutoMapper MapFrom can't take null values

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, automapper, mysql.data

I have a column `session_expires_at` in my `person` database table. This column is of type `DATETIME` and is nullable. In my code my `User` object represents this column with

```
public DateTime? SessionExpiresAt { get; set; }
```

When reading the user from the database with the **MySQL.Data** package I want to use AutoMapper to map the database result to the `User` object.

```
CreateMap<DbDataReader, User>()
    .ForMember(user => user.SessionExpiresAt,
        memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(dbDataReader => dbDataReader.IsDBNull(1) ? null : dbDataReader.GetDateTime(1)));
```

Since I know this value might be null I'm running a check before to avoid an exception. If that data is null, I want to assign null to the property, otherwise the datetime value. Unfortunately this error shows up

> There is no implicit conversion between 'null' and 'System.DateTime'

I played around a little bit and the `MapFrom` method is not able to take a null value. So if I would do this

```
CreateMap<DbDataReader, User>()
    .ForMember(user => user.SessionExpiresAt, memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(dbDataReader => null));
```

I get this error

> The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying
> the type arguments explicitly

I also tried this but it didn't help

```
CreateMap<DbDataReader, User>()
    .ForMember(user => user.SessionExpiresAt,
        memberOptions =>
        {
            memberOptions.AllowNull();
            memberOptions.MapFrom(dbDataReader => dbDataReader.GetDateTime(1));
        });
```

It is not possible for me to take a default value like `DateTime.Now` if the database value is null. It has to be possible to assign a null value.

How can I fix it so that I can assign null values to the property within the mapping rule? Maybe I can disable the mapping process if the value is null so it won't assign something?

Comment: why downvote? comment at least please

Comment: unfortunately not. I can't set a default value like `if null then take DateTime.Now` or something like that. The property is nullable and the value from the database might be null.

Comment: They important part being that you need to use `(DateTime?)null` in your ternary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others already mentioned in comments, your `MapFrom()` logic didn't work because of type mismatch between `null` and `DateTime`, as `DateTime` cannot be `null`. Only nullable `DateTime` can, so instead of using `null` you should use `(DateTime)null` or `default(DateTime?)`.

```cs
CreateMap<DbDataReader, User>()
    .ForMember(
        user => user.SessionExpiresAt,
        options => options.MapFrom(dbDataReader => dbDataReader.IsDBNull(1) ? default(DateTime?) : dbDataReader.GetDateTime(1)));
```

Another way and maybe a bit more readable is to use `PreCondition()`, where you can check before the actual mapping if the particular value from reader is null. If it is, the mapping for `SessionExpiresAt` will not happen.

```cs
CreateMap<DbDataReader, User>()
    .ForMember(
        user => user.SessionExpiresAt,
        options =>
        {
            options.PreCondition(dbDataReader => !dbDataReader.IsDBNull(1));
            options.MapFrom(dbDataReader => dbDataReader.GetDateTime(1));
        });
```